# Java,Selenium - stuck after opening TOR browser

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, tor

I'm working on webscraping hobby project. Stack is Java, Selenium, TOR, IntelliJ IDEA and Kali Linux. After few days of searching on google I managed to start TOR with Selenim but for this problem I didn't find answer on google. After I start project, TOR opens, makes connection, but than stops (no input of web address). IntelliJ is running all time, but nothing happening...

My code

```
WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
String torPath = "/home/username/Downloads/tor-browser/Browser/start-tor-browser";
String profilePath="/home/username/Downloads/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default";
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File(profilePath));
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File(torPath));
System.out.println("1");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary(binary);
options.setProfile(profile);
System.out.println("2");
options.setCapability(FirefoxOptions.FIREFOX_OPTIONS,options);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
System.out.println("3");
Constants.sleep(2000);
System.out.printf("4");
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

After running this code, I get messages "1" and "2", TOR opens, makes connection and that's it. IntelliJ running project (I must click stop button), but no errors or any other message...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I don't know why, but I figured out what to do to make it work... The code is ok and it's working perfectly. What makes the problem is closing the TOR browser. When I click x on TOR, it closes and IntelliJ stops running the project. But then, when you start again, it will stuck. I assume that problem is somewhere in TOR and profiles?
To make it work you must stop the project in IntelliJ and then it will close TOR properly.